# How to avoid "too many values to unpack"

Tags: python

My entire code here is posted, but only a fraction of it needs to be highlighted for this question.I only posted everything in case it would have been confusing if I omitted parts out.

```
from sympy.mpmath import *

class beam(object):
    """Model of a beam.
    """

    def __init__(self, E, I, L):
        """The class costructor.
        """
        self.E = E  # Young's modulus of the beam in N/m^2
        self.I = I  # Second moment of area of the beam in m^4
        self.L = L  # Length of the beam in m
        self.Loads = [(0.0, 0.0)]  # the list of loads applied to the beam

    def setLoads(self, Loads):
        '''This function allows multiple point loads to be applied to the beam
        using a list of tuples of the form (load, position)
        '''
        self.Loads = Loads
```

The above doesn't need any adjustment since it was given.

```
    def beamDeflection(self, Load, x):
        """A measure of how much the beam bends.
        """
        a = 2.5
        b = a + (x - a)
        (P1, A) = Load
        if 0 <= x <= a:
            v = ((P1*b*x)/(6*self.L*self.E*self.I))*((self.L**2)-(x**2)-(b**2))
        else:
            if a < x <= 5:
                v = ((P1*b)/(6*self.L*self.E*self.I)) * (((self.L/b)*((x-a)**3)) - (x**3) + (x*((self.L**2) - (b**2))))
        return v
```

Nothing really wrong here, but I would like to draw your attention to the (P1, A) = Load. It's part of the problem I'm trying to avoid.

```
    def getTotalDeflection(self, x):
        """A superposition of the deflection.
        """
        return sum(self.beamDeflection(loadall, x) for loadall in self.Loads)
```

I think that the above part is absolutely uneccessary and can be ignored, but it's here just in case.

```
    def getSlope(self, x):
        """Differentiate 'v' then input a value for x to obtain a result.
        """
        mp.dps = 15
        mp.pretty = True
        theta = sympy.diff(lambda x: self.beamDeflection(self.Loads, x), x)
        return theta

b = beam(8.0E9, 1.333E-4, 5.0)
b.setLoads([(900, 3.1), (700, 3.8), (1000, 4.2)])
print b.getSlope(1.0)
```

Here though, I'm trying to differentiate the first function I wrote (beamDeflection or v), but the problem I've encountered is that self.Loads is a list and so is Loads. That's why I think I'm getting the "too many values to unpack" error, but I'm not sure on how to avoid this. I though renaming "Load" in beamDeflection to "Weight" would work, but it becomes undefined. Could someone please offer guidance? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `self.Loads` is a one-item list which contains a two-items tuple, what seems unnecessary. When trying to unpack the list, `P1` receives the first item `(0.0, 0.0)` and `A` receives nothing, because there's nothing left, so the “too many values to unpack” error is raised. You'd probably want just:

```
self.Loads = (0.0, 0.0)
```

Also, there's no need to use parentheses when unpacking:

```
P1, A = Load
```

That's enough! Hope it helps!

Comment: The first two def shouldn't need editting since they were given, but I followed your suggestions and removed the square and normal brackets. The console drew my attention to "P1, A = Load" giving me a value error of "too many values to unpack".

Answer (score 2):

`self.Loads` is a list containing one tuple:

```
self.Loads = [(0.0, 0.0)]
```

Here, you **correctly** call `beamDeflection` on each item of the list:

```
return sum(self.beamDeflection(loadall, x) for loadall in self.Loads)
```

Here, you **incorrectly** call `beamDeflection` on the whole list:

```
theta = sympy.diff(lambda x: self.beamDeflection(self.Loads, x), x)
```

When you give the whole list to `beamDeflection`, it tries to unpack it as two values and fails.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm still not sure on how to avoid the error.

Comment: Well, what is `theta` supposed to do? Calculate deflection of one load? Or all of them?

Comment: All of them. Multiple loads will be placed on the beam, then beamDeflection is supposed to be differentiated to find the slope (of the bending beam). That's what theta is meant to be.

Comment: So if `Loads` has 3 tuples, you want to call `sympy.diff(beamDeflection(load0), beamDeflection(load1), beamDeflection(load2), x)`? Or something else?

Comment: I've included a little bit at the end of my code. It just shows what I'm aiming for and how exactly the load will be put into it. I'm not sure if the differentiation part is right though. Should I be using numerical or analytical differentiation for my problem? But I won't get onto that part if I don't solve the unpacking issue.

Comment: So, you have `Loads = [(900, 3.1), (700, 3.8), (1000, 4.2)]` and `x = 1.0`. `beamDeflection` can calculate deflection for each point: `d0 = beamDeflection((900, 3.1), 1.0)`, `d1 = beamDeflection((700, 3.8), 1.0)`, `d2 = beamDeflection((1000, 4.2), 1.0)` I don't know what `sympy.diff` does, so please explain how would you use it - do you want to calculate `sympy.diff(d0, d1, d2)` or `sympy.diff(d0, d1, d2, x)` or `sympy.diff(d0 + d1 + d2, x)`? In any case, you probably want to start with `all_deflecions=[self.beamDeflection(load, x) for load in self.Loads]`.

Comment: BTW, why are you creatigng a lambda? According to [this](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/calculus.html), `sympy.diff` does not expect a callable as argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98033/discussion-between-zvone-and-tablue).